# mysterious whitespace around SWF in fancybox

Tags: jquery, object, flash, fancybox, scale

I've got a swf in an iframe which I'm displaying in fancybox.  It looks great on my local server, but has extra whitespace when viewed online using FF10.  Crazy!  Same code, same browser, different server??  Never had that before.

Edit: Following some helpful suggestions, I've found that the online version (at the link below) looks perfect in Chrome, too.  So the issue seems to be with Firefox..  I've tried clearing caches and restarting and adding a version to the swf.html?ver=3 in the iframe link.

**Why does this page look different in FF when viewed at localhost vs the following link?!**

The demo is here: http://memelab.com.au/flipbook/index.html

I want the swf (a flipbook album) to fit the .fancybox-inner div exactly, no whitespace around the edges of the swf.  The images themselves have whitespace (i've just added a red edge to the first pages, which can be seen top and sides - bottom is cut off), but the edges of the swf can be seen by the shadow between pages and where the page corners lift.

I've had great trouble trimming away the whitespace, and found that putting the swf in an iframe gave me better results because i can specify scale="noScale" in the object params.

I've had trouble tracking down the issues in Firebug because there are so many overlapping height / width properties, so the success has been pretty much trial and error.  Just can't see why its different on upload!

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.various").fancybox({
        width       : 1008,
        height      : 792,
        minWidth    : 1048,
        minHeight   : 832,
        autoSize    : false,
        padding     : 20,
        wrapCSS     : 'pageflip'

    });
});
```

and the opject inside swf.html:

```
<object width="1008px" height="792px" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">

<param name="scale" value="noScale" />
<param name="salign" value="TL" />

<param value="transparent" name="wmode">
<param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">
<param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
<param value="pageflip.swf" name="movie">

<embed width="1008px" height="792px" wmode="direct" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="pageflip.swf" scale="noScale"></object>
```

I thought it might be a caching issue (old code), but putting ?ver=2 on the end doesn't work for me.

I'm stumped.. Any suggestions?  Thanks, Tim

(for the record, i'm running the file from localhost (XAMPP), and on a LAMP server on upload.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but is this what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.various").fancybox({
        width       : 1008,
        height      : 792,
        minWidth    : 1008,
        minHeight   : 792,
        autoSize    : false,
        padding     : 0,
        wrapCSS     : 'pageflip'

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, that does indeed remove the padding around .fancybox-outer.. 

my problem is that I'm seeing some whitespace (not sure if its padding, etc) on the _inside_ of the embed tag (i think) _only_ when I view the page online through firefox.  FF+local copy is perfect, Chrome+online version is perfect!

I'd like to upvote you when I get the rep.. for now I'll clarify my question - the issue seems to be browser related.

I'll clarify my question..

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, your problem is the 4.jpg image `http://memelab.com.au/flipbook/pages/4.jpg` - this actually has all that whitespace inside the image itself - making the iframe taller than it is wide. Other than that I cannot see any whitespace around your flash movie.

Comment: really!? whilst the images themselves have a good amount of whitespace, the swf's boundaries can be seen by the shadows it shows between the pages, and the edge of the pages as they turn.
I'm still seeing whitespace around the swf itself :( thanks for looking!

Comment: Thanks Jimmery - what browser are you using, please?  Chrome shows the correct result, FF10 shows a gap for me, TIA